# Unreal Engine 5 - Can’t Join another player’s Session through EOS

Tags: unreal-engine5, eos, epic-online-services

I'm trying to build a Peer-2-Peer multiplayer game using EOS (Epic Online Services) Online Subsystem in Unreal Engine 5.1.1.

**The Setup:**

- I configured my organization (product, application, client, client policy) in the Epic Developer Portal. Then I enabled in the project the plugins Online Subsystem EOS, EOS Shared, EOS Voice Chat & Socket Subsystem EOS, but not the Online Services EOS nor the Online Services EOS (Game Services).
- I configured in the Settings the Online Subsystem EOS, and the Artifact with the Settings in my Epic Developer Portal. And added the lines that the documentation specifies for the DefaultEngine.ini
- After that I created a normal multiplayer functionality with the Advanced Sessions Plugin, through blueprints where you can create a session or join a session. Here you login first with the "accountportal" authentication every time. I have tested with 2 different accounts in the Standalone Mode, and I have also tested it with another computer and another account with a packaged project.

**The Issue:**

- The player that hosts or creates the session, logs in well and creates the session well and it appears in the Developer Portal, so it works as it should. The problem comes when the player that wants to join that session tries to join.
- The second player logs in with a different account, then it looks for sessions, finds the one, tries to join it and shows up as successful (I have a print node after the FindSession node is successful), then this player's screen stays there in the Menu Level waiting to actually join the Host's Level, as if something was happening in the background, and then suddenly reloads the Menu Level as if something had gone wrong.

**The Logs:**
As this is happening, I'm looking at the logs to see why everything is happening the way that it is

*This is the Host's log:*

```
[2023.07.13-23.34.24:906][443]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOSAuth: BeginDesktopCrossplayLogin: Desktop crossplay is not ready: EOS_DesktopCrossplay_ApplicationNotBootstrapped
[2023.07.13-23.34.24:908][443]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: BeginDesktopCrossplayLogin: Desktop crossplay is not required for login
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:079][487]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: GenerateUserAuthByDeviceCode: Received FUserAuthToken
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:083][488]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Device auth to be continued at: <Redacted>
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:084][488]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Account Portal overlay failed to load for device auth continuation; falling back to browser based flow
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:085][488]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: LaunchAccountPortalWithPlatformBrowser: Launching with platform browser: <Redacted>
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:096][488]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: LaunchAccountPortalWithPlatformBrowser: Successfully launched with platform browser
[2023.07.13-23.34.25:199][510]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-HYhFpYpgv0eydPZZAkjrLA-TuxYFdGKfE6Z8WxqntPIGQ]
[2023.07.13-23.34.35:300][908]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-HYhFpYpgv0eydPZZAkjrLA-tbrmuLfOZ0yXeW6CnDDdiw]
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:558][377]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: NewUserToken: User ClientId: xyz...2jM AccountId: 816...e4e Access[Expires: 2023.07.14-01.34.45 Remaining: 7200.27] Refresh[Expires: 2024-01-09T23:34:45.268Z Remaining: 15552000.27] State: Valid
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:560][378]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Received FUserAuthToken
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:693][410]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Login complete: EOS_Success
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:896][460]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSMessaging: Attempting connection to Stomp. LocalUserId=[000...eec] Url=[<Redacted>]
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:902][461]LogOnlineFriend: Warning: EOS: [FUserManagerEOS::QueryBlockedPlayers] This method is not supported.
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:903][461]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Login Success
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:905][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_SetPermissionLevel() set to (0) for session (GameSession)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:905][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_SetMaxPlayers() set to (2) for session (GameSession)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:907][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_SetInvitesAllowed() set to (1) for session (GameSession)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:907][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_SetJoinInProgressAllowed() set to (1) for session (GameSession)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:908][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (PRESENCESEARCH) with value ()
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:913][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (NumPrivateConnections) with value (0)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:913][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (NumPublicConnections) with value (2)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:914][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (OwningUserId) with value (816ea60257ab40ac99cda20f7cccae4e|0002ca7980a64716a5de70af63452eec)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:915][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (OwningUserName) with value (narziz0)
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:915][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (bAntiCheatProtected) with value ()
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:916][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (bUsesStats) with value ()
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:916][461]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (bIsDedicated) with value ()
[2023.07.13-23.34.45:916][462]LogOnlineSession: EOS: EOS_SessionModification_AddAttribute() named (BuildUniqueId) with value (23058290)
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:365][572]LogOnlineSession: Display: OSS: Session creation completed. Automatic start is turned on, starting session now.
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:472][599]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Hosting Success
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:472][599]LogViewport: Display: Viewport MouseLockMode Changed, DoNotLock -> LockOnCapture
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:473][599]LogViewport: Display: Viewport MouseCaptureMode Changed, NoCapture -> CapturePermanently
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:473][599]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Opening Level
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:474][599]LogNet: Browse: /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/ThirdPersonMap?listen
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:474][599]LogLoad: LoadMap: /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/ThirdPersonMap?listen
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:475][599]LogWorld: BeginTearingDown for /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:476][599]LogWorld: UWorld::CleanupWorld for MainMenu, bSessionEnded=true, bCleanupResources=true
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:476][599]LogSlate: InvalidateAllWidgets triggered.  All widgets were invalidated
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:505][599]LogAudio: Display: Audio Device unregistered from world 'None'.
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:506][599]LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.47ms
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:543][599]LogAudio: Display: Audio Device (ID: 1) registered with world 'ThirdPersonMap'.
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:543][599]LogChaos: FPhysicsSolverBase::AsyncDt:-1.000000
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:544][599]LogAIModule: Creating AISystem for world ThirdPersonMap
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:546][599]LogWorldPartition: ULevel::OnLevelLoaded(ThirdPersonMap)(bIsOwningWorldGameWorld=1, bIsOwningWorldPartitioned=1, bIsValidLevelInstance=0, InitializeForMainWorld=1, InitializeForEditor=0, InitializeForGame=0)
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:546][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: WorldPartition initialize started...
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:546][599]LogWorldPartition: UWorldPartition::Initialize(Asset=ThirdPersonMap, IsEditor=0, bPIEWorldTravel=0 IsGame=1, IsCooking=0)
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:563][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: GenerateStreaming started...
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:563][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: GetPartitionedActors started...
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:564][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: GetPartitionedActors took 12 us
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:946][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: GenerateStreaming took 383 ms
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:946][599]LogContentBundle: [Container: ThirdPersonMap] Creating new contrainer.
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:946][599]LogWorldPartition: Display: WorldPartition initialize took 402 ms
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:948][599]LogLoad: Game class is 'EosTest_5GameMode'
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:949][599]LogNet: ReplicationDriverClass is null! Not using ReplicationDriver.
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:949][599]LogNetCore: DDoS detection status: detection enabled: 0 analytics enabled: 0
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:950][599]LogInit: WinSock: Socket queue. Rx: 131072 (config 131072) Tx: 131072 (config 131072)
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:951][599]LogNet: Created socket for bind address: 0.0.0.0:7777
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:951][599]PacketHandlerLog: Loaded PacketHandler component: Engine.EngineHandlerComponentFactory (StatelessConnectHandlerComponent)
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:952][599]LogNet: GameNetDriver IpNetDriver_0 IpNetDriver listening on port 7777
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:952][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting on static mesh StaticMesh /Game/LevelPrototyping/Meshes/SM_Cube.SM_Cube being ready before playing
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:952][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting on static mesh StaticMesh /Game/LevelPrototyping/Meshes/SM_QuarterCylinder.SM_QuarterCylinder being ready before playing
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:953][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting on static mesh StaticMesh /Game/LevelPrototyping/Meshes/SM_ChamferCube.SM_ChamferCube being ready before playing
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:954][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting on static mesh StaticMesh /Engine/EngineSky/SM_SkySphere.SM_SkySphere being ready before playing
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:954][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting on static mesh StaticMesh /Game/LevelPrototyping/Meshes/SM_Ramp.SM_Ramp being ready before playing
[2023.07.13-23.34.46:989][599]LogStaticMesh: Display: Waiting for static meshes to be ready 3/5 (/Engine/EngineSky/SM_SkySphere) ...
[2023.07.13-23.34.47:014][599]LogWorld: Bringing World /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/ThirdPersonMap.ThirdPersonMap up for play (max tick rate 0) at 2023.07.13-19.34.47
[2023.07.13-23.34.47:015][599]LogWorld: Bringing up level for play took: 0.002160
[2023.07.13-23.34.47:022][599]LogLoad: Took 0.550024 seconds to LoadMap(/Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/ThirdPersonMap)
[2023.07.13-23.34.47:765][652]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSPresence: Updating Presence to Online. LocalUserId=[816...e4e] RichText=[]
[2023.07.13-23.34.47:955][669]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSMessaging: Succesfully connected to Stomp. LocalUserId=[000...eec]
[2023.07.13-23.36.48:415][846]LogDerivedDataCache: C:/Users/myUser/AppData/Local/UnrealEngine/Common/DerivedDataCache: Maintenance finished in +00:00:46.091 and deleted 0 files with total size 0 MiB. Scanned 27896 files in 19576 folders with total size 2982 MiB.
```

- - 

I don't really see any problems here, in the Host's log, but I don't know if I'm missing something.

- - 

Then this is where the problem happens...
*The Joiner's log:*

```
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:020][464]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOSAuth: BeginDesktopCrossplayLogin: Desktop crossplay is not ready: EOS_DesktopCrossplay_ApplicationNotBootstrapped
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:021][465]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: BeginDesktopCrossplayLogin: Desktop crossplay is not required for login
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:160][501]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: GenerateUserAuthByDeviceCode: Received FUserAuthToken
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:164][502]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Device auth to be continued at: <Redacted>
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:165][502]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Account Portal overlay failed to load for device auth continuation; falling back to browser based flow
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:166][502]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: LaunchAccountPortalWithPlatformBrowser: Launching with platform browser: <Redacted>
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:171][502]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: LaunchAccountPortalWithPlatformBrowser: Successfully launched with platform browser
[2023.07.13-23.34.42:286][529]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-4j6eSisUAEmI74wxZcTDhw-GEGET8wxb0OrmTGFGwslKQ]
[2023.07.13-23.34.52:370][ 39]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-4j6eSisUAEmI74wxZcTDhw-mOrXGWhgUUGOjnMmTN3YKg]
[2023.07.13-23.35.02:463][531]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-4j6eSisUAEmI74wxZcTDhw-3-TCKkRGJE23F3BmXKtqFg]
[2023.07.13-23.35.12:570][ 45]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-4j6eSisUAEmI74wxZcTDhw-9BhendWMqkaFUv1QUBILcw]
[2023.07.13-23.35.22:688][437]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[OAuth], OperationName=[TokenGrantv2], Url=[<Redacted>], HttpStatus=[400], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.account.oauth.authorization_pending], NumericErrorCode=[1012], ErrorMessage=[The authorization server request is still pending as the end user has yet to visit and enter the verification code.], CorrId=[EOS-6o7AvJ_UR0Sizivh5J_1Vw-4j6eSisUAEmI74wxZcTDhw-o-c9qAdK4EeJfmaiLnvzcg]
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:245][ 48]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: NewUserToken: User ClientId: xyz...2jM AccountId: f2f...2d3 Access[Expires: 2023.07.14-01.35.32 Remaining: 7200.65] Refresh[Expires: 2024-01-09T23:35:32.657Z Remaining: 15552000.66] State: Valid
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:248][ 49]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Received FUserAuthToken
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:369][ 79]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSAuth: UserAuthGenerated: Login complete: EOS_Success
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:984][237]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSMessaging: Attempting connection to Stomp. LocalUserId=[000...f12] Url=[<Redacted>]
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:988][238]LogOnlineFriend: Warning: EOS: [FUserManagerEOS::QueryBlockedPlayers] This method is not supported.
[2023.07.13-23.35.33:988][238]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Login Success
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:276][304]LogScript: Script Msg: Found a session. Ping is 0
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:394][335]LogScript: Script Msg: Found a session. Ping is 0
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:395][335]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] # of sessions: 1
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:395][335]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Finding Success
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:396][335]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSSessions: The Social Overlay will not know about this session (GameSession).
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:513][365]LogOnlineSession: OSS: Join session: traveling to MyIP:7777
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:513][365]LogBlueprintUserMessages: [WBP_MainMenu_C_0] Joining Session
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:514][365]LogViewport: Display: Viewport MouseLockMode Changed, DoNotLock -> LockOnCapture
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:514][365]LogViewport: Display: Viewport MouseCaptureMode Changed, NoCapture -> CapturePermanently
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:515][365]LogNet: Browse: MyIP/Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:515][365]LogInit: WinSock: Socket queue. Rx: 32768 (config 32768) Tx: 32768 (config 32768)
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:516][365]LogNet: Created socket for bind address: 0.0.0.0:0
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:517][365]LogNet: IpConnection_0 setting maximum channels to: 32767
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:518][365]PacketHandlerLog: Loaded PacketHandler component: Engine.EngineHandlerComponentFactory (StatelessConnectHandlerComponent)
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:524][365]LogHandshake: Stateless Handshake: NetDriverDefinition 'GameNetDriver' CachedClientID: 1
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:525][365]LogNet: Game client on port 7777, rate 100000
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:525][365]LogNetVersion: EosTest_5 1.0.0.0, NetCL: 23058290, EngineNetVer: 30, GameNetVer: 0 (Checksum: 695384142)
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:530][367]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSPresence: Updating Presence to Online. LocalUserId=[f2f...2d3] RichText=[]
[2023.07.13-23.35.34:756][425]LogEOSSDK: LogEOSMessaging: Succesfully connected to Stomp. LocalUserId=[000...f12]
[2023.07.13-23.35.44:516][917]LogNet: Initial Connect Diagnostics: Sent '9' packets in last '10.003015' seconds, no packets received yet.
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:517][499]LogNet: Initial Connect Diagnostics: Sent '10' packets in last '10.000485' seconds, no packets received yet.
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:532][503]LogNet: Warning: UNetConnection::Tick: Connection TIMED OUT. Closing connection.. Elapsed: 20.00, Real: 20.00, Good: 20.00, DriverTime: 20.02, Threshold: 20.00, [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:532][503]LogNet: Error: UEngine::BroadcastNetworkFailure: FailureType = ConnectionTimeout, ErrorString = UNetConnection::Tick: Connection TIMED OUT. Closing connection.. Elapsed: 20.00, Real: 20.00, Good: 20.00, DriverTime: 20.02, Threshold: 20.00, [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID, Driver = PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:533][503]LogNet: Warning: Network Failure: PendingNetDriver[ConnectionTimeout]: UNetConnection::Tick: Connection TIMED OUT. Closing connection.. Elapsed: 20.00, Real: 20.00, Good: 20.00, DriverTime: 20.02, Threshold: 20.00, [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:534][503]LogNet: NetworkFailure: ConnectionTimeout, Error: 'UNetConnection::Tick: Connection TIMED OUT. Closing connection.. Elapsed: 20.00, Real: 20.00, Good: 20.00, DriverTime: 20.02, Threshold: 20.00, [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID'
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:535][503]LogNet: UNetConnection::Close: [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID, Channels: 2, Time: 2023.07.13-23.35.54
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:536][503]LogNet: UNetConnection::SendCloseReason:
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:536][503]LogNet:  - Result=ConnectionTimeout, ErrorContext="ConnectionTimeout"
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:536][503]LogNet: UChannel::Close: Sending CloseBunch. ChIndex == 0. Name: [UChannel] ChIndex: 0, Closing: 0 [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:539][504]LogNet: Browse: /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu?closed
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:539][504]LogNet: DestroyNamedNetDriver IpNetDriver_0 [PendingNetDriver]
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:540][504]LogExit: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0 shut down
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:540][504]LogNet: Connection failed; returning to Entry
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:541][504]LogLoad: LoadMap: /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu?closed
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:541][504]LogWorld: BeginTearingDown for /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:542][504]LogWorld: UWorld::CleanupWorld for MainMenu, bSessionEnded=true, bCleanupResources=true
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:542][504]LogSlate: InvalidateAllWidgets triggered.  All widgets were invalidated
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:574][504]LogAudio: Display: Audio Device unregistered from world 'None'.
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:575][504]LogNet: UChannel::CleanUp: ChIndex == 0. Closing connection. [UChannel] ChIndex: 0, Closing: 0 [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: IpConnection_0, Driver: PendingNetDriver IpNetDriver_0, IsServer: NO, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:575][504]LogNet: UNetConnection::PendingConnectionLost. [UNetConnection] RemoteAddr: MyIP:7777, Name: None, Driver: PendingNetDriver None, IsServer: YES, PC: NULL, Owner: NULL, UniqueId: INVALID bPendingDestroy=0
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:576][504]LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.61ms
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:604][504]LogAudio: Display: Audio Device (ID: 1) registered with world 'MainMenu'.
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:604][504]LogChaos: FPhysicsSolverBase::AsyncDt:-1.000000
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:604][504]LogAIModule: Creating AISystem for world MainMenu
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:605][504]LogLoad: Game class is 'GM_MainMenu_C'
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:605][504]LogWorld: Bringing World /Game/ThirdPerson/Maps/MainMenu.MainMenu up for play (max tick rate 0) at 2023.07.13-19.35.54
[2023.07.13-23.35.54:606][504]LogWorld: Bringing up level for play took: 0.000407
```

- - 

I don't know why, but there's a timeout happening, I turned off my Windows' Firewalls and still have the same problem. I really don't know what could be happening. Thanks in advance, I added a lot of context because I know that it's always really good to have a nice idea of wtf is happening haha, so yeah, I would greatly appreciate some input.

Edit: I do see in the Joiner's log, the mention of the IP "MyIP:7777", and I don't know if this even makes sense, but when I write that in my browser, while the games are running, the browser also times out, so maybe something with the Joiner grabbing the wrong IP?

Comment: I'd rather try https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh wow, can't believe I didn't know about that .-. (honestly, not being sarcastic)
Writing it up there right now. Greatly appreciate it @MarcinOrlowski !